# ionic run android shows black and white screens before main app page

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am testing my ionic app on an Android phone using:

```js
ionic run android
```

When the app starts the splash screen shows for a few seconds as expected, and then the screen goes black for @1 second and then white for @2 seconds and then the main app page appears.

Is there any way to prevent the black and white pages appearing? I read somewhere that a black page appears when there is no splash page but I do have a splash page and it appears fine.

Comment: What about disabling autohiding of the splashscreen and hiding it when the app is completely ready?

Comment: How do I know when the app is completely ready?

Comment: Usually it's enough to put `navigator.splashscreen.hide();` (or `$cordovaSplashscreen.hide();` if using ngCordova) within `$ionicPlatform.ready()` into your first state's controller. You can then tweak it depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks Kate I will try that out.

Comment: Yup that did the job thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you worked it out, could you please mark the answer as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable splashscreen auto-hiding and hide it from your code when your app is completely ready.

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
});
```

or when using `ngCordova`:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    $cordovaSplashscreen.hide();
});
```

Should be run somehow when your first state is ready, usually it's sufficent to put it into your first state's controller for testing.